# using same implementation with different lifestyles Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have a class like this:

```
public FooRepo : IFooRepo
{
   public FooRepo(IDbContextFactory factory)
   {
      context = factory.GetContext();
   }
}
```

In my app I register everything with `LifeStyle.PerWebRequest`, 
but now I need to call one Method which uses this `IFooRepo` like this (because it's gonna take about an hour):

```
{
 ...
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => RequestReport(number));
 ...
}
private void RequestReport(int number)
{
// IFooRepo needed here
}
```

the problem is that I need this `IFooRepo` with PerWebRequest lifestyle most of the time, and I needed here in the thread also to stay alive, also it has a dependency `IDbContextFactory` which I don't know if I need to register it also in a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well then register your `FooRepo` twice and [setup service override](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-Dependencies.ashx#In-line_service_dependencies_1) for whoever uses in on the `ThreadPool` to use the other component. Easy.

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic do I have to register the IDbContextFactory twice also ? and what is "setup service override" ?

Comment: You need to set up twice whatever doesn't make sense to be per-web-request in that given context. I updated the answer with the link to documentation about service overrides

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic and instead of constructor injection I have to use resolve by string key ?

Comment: no. Use service override in a manner transparent to the component's implementing type.

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic I have constructors in different classes Class1(IFooRepo repo) and Class2(IFooRepo repo) , class1 needs by default perwebrequest and class2 needs transient, this can be somehow specified, or I do .Resolve(key

Comment: Make the Per-web-request one default (by registering it first) and the other one use via service override on component that needs it.